# Rails SyntaxError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, error-handling, localhost

Whenever I start my rails server I'm getting the following error:

```
SyntaxError - /Users/Bangner/Desktop/wednesday/myapp/vendor/bundle/gems/devise-3.1.0/app/controllers/devise/sessions_controller.rb:52: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting end-of-input:
  zeus (0.13.3) lib/zeus/load_tracking.rb:50:in `'
  zeus (0.13.3) lib/zeus/load_tracking.rb:50:in `load'
  zeus (0.13.3) lib/zeus/load_tracking.rb:50:in `load'
```

My Session controller:

```
class Devise::SessionsController < DeviseController
  prepend_before_filter :require_no_authentication, :only => [ :new, :create ]
  prepend_before_filter :allow_params_authentication!, :only => :create
  prepend_before_filter { request.env["devise.skip_timeout"] = true }

  # GET /resource/sign_in
  def new
    self.resource = resource_class.new(sign_in_params)
    clean_up_passwords(resource)
    respond_with(resource, serialize_options(resource))
    end
  end

  # POST /resource/sign_in
  def create
    self.resource = warden.authenticate!(auth_options)
    set_flash_message(:notice, :signed_in) if is_navigational_format?
    sign_in(resource_name, resource)
    respond_with resource, :location => after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  end

  # DELETE /resource/sign_out
  def destroy
    redirect_path = after_sign_out_path_for(resource_name)
    signed_out = (Devise.sign_out_all_scopes ? sign_out : sign_out(resource_name))
    set_flash_message :notice, :signed_out if signed_out && is_navigational_format?

    # We actually need to hardcode this as Rails default responder doesn't
    # support returning empty response on GET request
    respond_to do |format|
      format.all { head :no_content }
      format.any(*navigational_formats) { redirect_to redirect_path }
    end
  end

  protected

  def sign_in_params
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.sanitize(:sign_in)
  end

  def serialize_options(resource)
    methods = resource_class.authentication_keys.dup
    methods = methods.keys if methods.is_a?(Hash)
    methods << :password if resource.respond_to?(:password)
    { :methods => methods, :only => [:password] }
  end

  def auth_options
    { :scope => resource_name, :recall => "#{controller_path}#new" }
  end
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On line 11 you have an extra `end` statement.

```
  def new
    self.resource = resource_class.new(sign_in_params)
    clean_up_passwords(resource)
    respond_with(resource, serialize_options(resource))
    end    ### <--- this is the line that's causing your error
  end
```

Comment: stupid mistake..didn't realize that file had been edited at all.